# Read properties file from an openshift directory

Tags: spring-boot, openshift, application.properties

Apparently i have a basic spring boot application that i need to deploy in openshift. The openshift contains aan application.yml/application.properties in it in a var/config directory. After deployment of the application in openshift, I need to read the propert/yml file from the directory in my application. Is there any process how to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

How are you building your container? Are you using S2I? Building the container yourself with Docker/podman? And what's "var/config" relative to? When you say "the OpenShift contains", what do you mean.

In short, an application running in an OpenShift container has access to whatever files you add to the container. There is effectively no such thing as an "OpenShift directory": you have access to what is in the container (and what is mounted to it). The whole point of containers is that you are limited to that.

So yourquestion probably boils down to, "how do I add a config file into my container". That will, however, depend on where the file is. Most tools for building containers will grab the standard places you'd have a config file, but if you have it somewhere non-standard you will have to copy it into the container yourself.

See [this Spring Boot guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/) for how to use a Dockerfile to do it yourself. See [here for using S2I to assemble the image](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.9/openshift_images/create-images.html#images-create-s2i_create-images) (what you'd do if you were using the developer console of OpenShift to pull dir. (In general S2I tends to do what is needed automatically, but if your config is somewhere odd you may have to write an assemble script.)

[This Dockerfile doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) on copying files into a container might also be helpful.

Comment: Hi David, var/config is basically a remote directory in openshift where the application.properties file is stored . I need to override this properties file in my springboot application deployed there .

Comment: What do you mean "remote directory in OpenShift"? There is no such thing.

Comment: If you have it on some kind of persistent volume, here are the docs on how to mount those (and details on PVs and PVCs in general): https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.9/storage/understanding-persistent-storage.html